# Can I use MRJob to process big files in local mode?

Tags: mrjob

I have a relatively big file - around 10GB to process. I suspect it won't fit into my laptop's RAM, if MRJob decides to sort it in RAM or something similar.

At the same time, I don't want to setup hadoop or EMR - the job is not urgent and I can simple start worker before going to sleep and get the results the next morning. In other words, I'm quite happy with local mode. I know, the performance won't be perfect but it's ok for now.

So can it process such 'big' files at a single weak machine? If yes - what would you recommend to do (besides setting a custom tmp dir to point to the filesystem, not to the ramdisk which will be exhausted quickly). Let's assume we use version 0.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

I think the RAM size won't be an issue with the python runner of mrjob. The output of each step should be written out to temporary file on disk, so it should not fill up the RAM I believe. Dumping output to disk is the way it should be with Hadoop (and the reason why it is slow due to IO). So I would just run the job and see how it goes.

If the RAM size is an issue, you can create enough swap space on your laptop to make it at least run, thought it will be slow if the partition isn't on SSD.